# Accidentally dismissed the decompiler prompt in Intellij Idea, how can I enable it?

Tags: intellij-idea, decompiler

I accidentally dismissed the decompiler license agreement (pressed Escape) in Intellij Idea when it first popped up. How can I turn this feature back on as it seems not to work and the setting to reset this is nowhere to be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wasting time and panicking - just restart your IDE and it'll prompt you again.

Comment: I wish somebody else would have posted this question somewhere so that I wouldn't spend so much time trying to find this out.